# Finding the largest number in a list of numbers passed throught the command line in Python

Tags: python

I have a requirement to accept a list of numbers through commnad line and print the largest number. So I wrote this Python script

```
import sys

arg_list = sys.argv[:]
num_list = arg_list[1:]
if (len(num_list) == 0):
    print "Please pass a list on numbers as an argument"
else:
    max_num = max(num_list)
    print "The largest number is " + str(max_num)
```

Now this code is not working fine for the list 1, 5, 77, 8 but I do not understand what wrong I have done. Would anyone help me out please?

Comment: Probably because the list actually contains `['1','5','77','8']`

Answer (score 3):

The arguments to a program are always strings, you need to convert your `num_list` to integers:

```
num_list = map(int, num_list)
```

This could throw a ValueError exception if any of the input is not a valid number, you may want to catch that:

```
try:
    num_list = map(int, num_list)
except ValueError:
    print 'Please enter only integers'
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast them to ints first

e.g.

```
max(int(num) for num in num_list)
```

Comment: You don't need an inner list, you can do `max(int(num) for num in num_list)`

Answer (score 1):

You can covert them to integers, or you can sort the integer values:

```
>>> num_list = ['1','5','77','8']
>>> sorted(num_list, key=int, reverse=True)[0]
'77'
```

Comment: or just `max(num_list, key=int)`